# Laravel: api to get address details from qr code of aadhar card

Tags: php, laravel, aadhaar

I am developing an application which scans the QR/Bar code of uploaded Aadhar code and gives the address details from that.

Is it possible?

Is there any API to get the address details from scanning QR code of Indian Aadhar card?

Comment: How are you going to get the qr codes in your Laravel application? Upload image files?

Comment: @Jerodev, upload image files